# Measure a view before render for android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-view

Before doing `windowManager.addView()` I want to get the height and width of the view that will appear on the screen.
But this code only gives the height correct.

```
private fun getViewHeightWidth(view: View): View {
    val display = windowManager?.defaultDisplay
    val deviceWidth: Int = display?.width!!
    val deviceHeight: Int = display?.height!!
    val widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(deviceWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    val heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    return view
}
```

Is it possible?

params I gave to addView

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
```

Comment: What `LayoutParams` are you providing to `addView` as these affect how the child view is measured.

Comment: @Andrew I added the params I gave.